# How to remove prefix in array keys

Tags: php, arrays, key, implode

I try to remove a prefix in array keys and every attempt is failing. What I want to achieve is to:

Having: `Array ( [attr_Size] => 3 [attr_Colour] => 7 )`

To Get: `Array ( [Size] => 3 [Colour] => 7 )`

Your help will be much appreciated...

Comment: So you just want to remove `attr_` from your array keys? What has this got to do with `implode()`? Should `attr_my_prop` become `my_prop`, `prop` or something else? Most importantly, why? Can we see your "failing" code please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the ways To Get:`Array ( [Size] => 3 [Colour] => 7 )` From your `Having: Array ( [attr_Size] => 3 [attr_Colour] => 7 )`

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach($Your_arr as $key => $value) {

list($dummy, $newkey) = explode('_', $key);
$new_arr[$newkey] = $value;

}
```

If you think there'll be multiple underscores in keys just replace first line inside foreach with  `list($dummy, $newkey) = explode('attr_', $key);`

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your question, you don't have to use `implode()` to get what you want.

```
define(PREFIX, 'attr_');

$array = array('attr_Size' => 3, 'attr_Colour' => 7);

$prefixLength = strlen(PREFIX);

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  if (substr($key, 0, $prefixLength) === PREFIX)
  {
    $newKey = substr($key, $prefixLength);
    $array[$newKey] = $value;
    unset($array[$key]);
  }
}

print_r($array); // shows: Array ( [Size] => 3 [Colour] => 7 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the first character that you'd like to retain in each key starts with an uppercase letter, you can simply left-trim lowercase letters and underscores and voila.  To create a "mask" of all lowercase letters and the underscore, you could use `a..z_`, but because `attr_` is the known prefix, `_art` will do.  My snippet, admittedly, is narrowly suited to the asker's sample data, does not call `explode()` to create a temporary array, and does not make multiple function calls per iteration.  Use contentiously.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ntgpq))

```
$array = [
    'attr_Size' => 3,
    'attr_Colour' => 7
];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $result[ltrim($key, '_art')] = $value;
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Size' => 3,
  'Colour' => 7,
)
```