# key array PHP - Merge key

Tags: php, arrays

My problem solve after read this post .. 
[How to remove prefix in array keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614397/implode-array-keys-only)

but i've another problem about key array again 
I've array like this (array multidimentional)

```
Array([0,123]=> Array ([0]=>value[1]=>value) [1,124]=> Array ([0]=>value[1]=>value) [2,125]=> Array ([0]=>value[1]=>value)
```

0 is key, 123 is my dummy data .. 
0 using for looping and 123 is using too in another purpose

i want to add join 123 and 124 like this ..

before join

```
[0,123] [1,124] [1,125].....
```

after join ,  i want to like this

```
[0,123,124] [1,125].....
```

May you know , what should i do ? Do you know solution or advive what function to solve it?

Thankyou so much guys !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_chunk($array, 3);` where $array will be your array and second parameter will be how elements you want in each splitted array..Hope this will help.

```
For eg.
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
        )

)
```

Comment: Oh .. i just know about array chunk .. i want search more again about array chunk .. Thankyou so much@prashant ..

Comment: sorry i was try .. not array_chunk @prashant :( . i want only key to modification.. sorry my question isn't clear its my fault .. i was edit .. may you know ?

Comment: i want to make table like this link ... http://home.deib.polimi.it/matteucc/Clustering/tutorial_html/hierarchical.html